# How to use "NOT LIKE" for a column values in SQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-like

So I have a table like this:

```
X.        Y.
34560     eudhkri 34560 abc
26558     hsyrb 26558 ax
3666      dhurb 3666 yzhdj
3666      dhfhjf 366688 avh
233       abc 233 hdhsijej
```

Since characters in the `Y` column are changeable (meaning they have different number of letters) I thought I might use the `NOT LIKE` operator to exclude the rows where the `X` value is in the `Y` column.

However, I don't know how. It is not possible to just write it every values of X down. Also, I wrote the 4th row specifically to show you I can't exclude this data since the numbers are not same, so using % might cause some trouble.

Comment: It's unclear to me if you want to include the rows where Y contains X, or if you want to exclude them

Comment: I wanted to exclude, thanks for answering and edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to use the like operatoe you could try this way

```
select *
from my_table 
where y NOT like concat('%',x,'%')
```

or

```
select *
from my_table 
where y NOT like concat('% ', x,' %')
```

Comment: This excludes the row you specifically put in to show you could not exclude (row 4).

Answer (score 3):

You could use a regular expression:

```
WHERE y ~ ('\m' || x || '\M')
```

`\m` marks the beginning of a word, `\M` the end.